# Good SQL Agent job wrapper... TRY/CATCH, Custom logging. (Review and provide input)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I'm looking for input on a small snippet of code i wrote. We use SQL Agent jobs to prepare big databases from production, before we ship the to test-environments. To get better feel for duration of the various truncate, index-rebuilds, anonymization in the many agent job steps, i've been looking at logging each job step to a log table. I've created a "Start log event" SP, which returns the PK INT of the logevent. And a "Complete log event" SP, which updates timestamps and returnCodes.

In order to grab the possible errors, i'm introducing TRY/CATCH, and are THROWing it afterwards, to make errors manageable by SQL Agent browser.

I also want it to dynamically grab the agent job name and step name, to make it really re-usable.

Below you can find an example of a stepID with this wrapper.

What do you think? input and ideas are appreciated.
(Yes, truncate table will fail in snippet.. its on purpose)

```
DECLARE @id INT                     -- ID variable used for the RestoreCommandLog returned ID
DECLARE @ErrNumber INT              -- Error Number code if exception is thrown
DECLARE @ErrMessage NVARCHAR(2048)  -- Error message text for human interactions
DECLARE @job_Name NVARCHAR(255)     -- SQL Agent job name
DECLARE @Step_Name NVARCHAR(255)    -- SQL Agent job step name
DECLARE @Command NVARCHAR(MAX)      -- SQL Statement associated with

-- Get Sql Agent job info
SELECT  @job_Name = CAST(t1.name AS NVARCHAR(255)), @Step_Name =  CAST(t2.step_name AS NVARCHAR(255)),  @Command = t2.command FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs t1 INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps t2 ON t1.job_id = t2.job_id AND t2.step_id = $(ESCAPE_NONE(STEPID))  AND t2.job_id = $(ESCAPE_NONE(JOBID))

/****************************************
            --- MAIN ---        
****************************************/
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases WHERE name = N'<my database>' and state_desc = 'ONLINE')
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC @id = [Operation].[dbo].sp_AddRestoreCommandLogEvent @CommandName = @job_Name, @CommandMessage = @Step_Name, @sqlstring = @Command

        /***    DO YOUR STUFF HERE  ***/
        USE <my_database>
        EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'TRUNCATE TABLE --?' 
        EXEC [Operation].[dbo].sp_CompleteRestoreCommandLogEvent @EventId = @id, @ReturnCode = '0', @ErrorMessage = 'Success'

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT @ErrNumber = ERROR_NUMBER(), @ErrMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        EXEC [Operation].[dbo].sp_CompleteRestoreCommandLogEvent @EventId = @id, @ReturnCode = @ErrNumber, @ErrorMessage = @ErrMessage;
        THROW
    END CATCH; 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    EXEC [Operation].[dbo].sp_AddRestoreCommandLogEvent @CommandName = @job_Name, @CommandMessage = @Step_Name, @sqlstring = @Command, @ReturnCode = '-1', @ErrorMessage = 'Warning - object is this step was not found, skipping logic'
END
```

Comment: `sp_MSforeachtable` is undocumented - avoid using it. There are many [other ways to do what you are trying to achieve](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10281905/1387418).

Comment: the example use of sp_MSforeachtable was not the main purpose here... the /***    DO YOUR STUFF HERE  ***/ section was just to give an example on a command. The focus is the structure around it, as a logging "framework" if you will to be used in SQL Agent jobs.